# Bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I managed to mix up my repositories due to unfamiliarity to github, and now I can't get this to run anymore at all. I have tried everything and have only managed to break it more. The last thing I did which broke it completely was try to use the quick start css / javascript links on my application.html.erb

now when you click the calendar icon nothing shows up, before you could click the dates and it would appear in the box but the blue surrounding the date when you click it wouldn't.

events.js.coffee

```
   $ ->
    $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker

 return
```

_form.html.erb page

```
     <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-           calendar">      </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

application.js page

```
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require moment
 //= require bootstrap
 //= require bootstrap.min
 //= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
 //= require_self
 //= require_tree .
```

So I got all my javascript linked through the asset pipeline (hopefully in the correct order)
and not using application.html.erb except for the following few link tags

application.html.erb

```
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" =>    true %>
     <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>



        <script type="text/javascript"                       src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="UTF-8">
```

```
     <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-     datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

So my error is that it isn't working properly. What I mean by that is if you click the year portion on top it freaks out and displays something like this
       2014
JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJUL
 etc etc.

also the buttons when you click them are having a black bar through them and the dates when you click them don't turn blue

I would really appreciate any help you experts could give me. Thanks

Comment: can you clarify your problem more? maybe post code for application.html.erb or talk about github problem more

Comment: updated, please tell me if you need more info